# Error using Place Picker: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller

Tags: android, google-maps

hey guys i am facing this weird issue whenever i run my code below the place picker appears but within a sec it disappears and it goes back to my mail activity. I saw this code somewhere on internet and wanted to try it.i tried looking for similar issues but couldnt find it.i am learning android so please help .Thanks in advance

```
public class Plcpickr extends AppCompatActivity {
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
Button btn;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plcpickr);
    btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new 
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(Plcpickr.this), 
 PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | 
GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
  @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            StringBuilder stBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String placename = String.format("%s", place.getName());
            String latitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().latitude);
            String longitude = String.valueOf(place.getLatLng().longitude);
            String address = String.format("%s", place.getAddress());
            stBuilder.append("Name: ");
            stBuilder.append(placename);
            stBuilder.append("\n");
            stBuilder.append("Latitude: ");
            stBuilder.append(latitude);
            stBuilder.append("\n");
            stBuilder.append("Logitude: ");
            stBuilder.append(longitude);
            stBuilder.append("\n");
            stBuilder.append("Address: ");
            stBuilder.append(address);
            t.setText(stBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Logcat error**

> /com.example.jimmy.placepicker I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy 11-09 12:41:38.400 10227-10227/com.example.jimmy.placepicker W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller; 11-09 12:41:38.400 10227-10227/com.example.jimmy.placepicker D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at

Comment: can you put logcat

Comment: @SharartiKAKA 

    11-09 12:41:38.400 10227-10227/com.example.jimmy.placepicker 
     I/dalvikvm: Could not find method 
     android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced 
     from method com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy
    11-09 12:41:38.400 10227-10227/com.example.jimmy.placepicker 
     W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: 
    Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller 
    ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
11-09 12:41:38.400 10227-10227/com.example.jimmy.placepicker D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012

Comment: at exactly which place this error occurr

Comment: It comes at the end after i click on the button

Comment: which ok button you are not explaining your situations

Comment: in the code above 
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
my placepicker is called on the click of a button in the code above 
so when i run the code the error doesnt appear but when i click on the button to call Placepicker the error appears

Comment: can you place your xml too ?

Comment: if there is no problem in your xml consider changing your Google API key. Go to your google developer console and then project , create new key and use it,

Comment: i have already tried it but nothing happened still the same error

Comment: which device are you testing on ?

Comment: i am testing on bluestack, and i tried using google maps in my another app and its working fine

Comment: u must test on real device